# How to convert portable pdb (ppdb) to mdb?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, ppdb

Mono version 5.x dropped mdb support and generates portable pdb instead. Is it possible to convert new style portable pdb to old style mdb?
Specifically interested to do it on mac/linux.

I am aware of the [pdb2mdb](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/pdb2mdb) tool, but afaik it works for full pdb on windows, not for portable pdb.